# Error Extra \else \include after using bibtex for each \include using chapterbib

Tags: bibliographies, koma-script, include

Thanks first of all for the previous times that I have already found answers to my problems without having to post anything!

My problems is as follows: when I compile my main file only after I have done Bibtex on my chapter, it gives the following errors:

```
! Extra \else.
\@include ...ediate \closeout \@partaux \fi \else 
                                                  \deadcycles \z@ \@nameuse ...
l.26 \include{MWE}

I'm ignoring this; it doesn't match any \if.
```

Same for Extra \fi.

An MWE for the main file is:

```
\documentclass[
        twoside,openright,titlepage,numbers=noenddot,headinclude,
                cleardoublepage=empty,
                BCOR=5mm,paper=b5,fontsize=9.5pt, DIV=14,
                dutch,american, % Languages
                ]{scrbook} 
\input{classicthesis-config}                

\begin{document}
\include{MWE} 
\end{document}
```

For the chapter MWE it is:

```
\chapter{MWE}
\label{MWE}

\noindent \lipsum \cite{Abramowitz:1972}

\bibliographystyle{aa}
\bibliography{Bibliography}
```

I further use

```
 \PassOptionsToPackage{round,authoryear}{natbib}
```

and

```
\usepackage{lipsum}
```

in the `classicthesis-config.tex` and the following style file:
[A&A journal](http://ftp.edpsciences.org/pub/aa/bibtex/aa.bst)

---

Compilable example:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{        Abramowitz:1972,
  author    = {{Abramowitz}, M. and {Stegun}, I.~A.},
  title     = "{Handbook of Mathematical Functions: with formulas, graphs, and mathematical tables}",
  keywords  = {Functions, Mathematics},
  booktitle = {Handbook of mathematical functions},
  address   = {New York},
  publisher = {Dover},
  year      = 1972,
  adsurl    = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1970hmfw.book.....A},
  adsnote   = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-chap.tex}
\chapter{MWE}
\lipsum \cite{Abramowitz:1972}
%\bibliographystyle{aa}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{scrbook} 
\usepackage[round,authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\include{\jobname-chap}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you mention classicthesis but your example code doesn't use that package at all?

Comment: The example just generates `! Undefined control sequence.
l.4 \noindent \lipsum` please edit it so that it generates the error in the question.

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/20235887#20235887 <- Please test this MWE. Copy the content to a new file, run it. It contains *all* the information you have given us. I cannot know, what might be in your config file, that might lead to the behaviour.

Comment: Please post the MWE in your question. Several reasons: (1) your question should be useful to other users, even if the external link changes or disappears; (2) preparing the MWE is part of diagnosing the issue, and it is the part which you can do even if you cannot get to the final diagnosis without help; (3) many people will be extremely reluctant to download a `.zip` posted by a complete stranger on a public site. (I won't do this.) How to create a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Note that the non standard `aa` bib style is not needed you can use `\bibliographystyle{plain}` and get the same error looks like  natbib and chapterbib are not wanting to play together

Comment: This is a duplicate: remove `[sectionbib]` and add `\KOMAoption{bibliography}{leveldown}`

Comment: Note that once you had provided a MWE showing it was a chapterbib/natbib problem, searching on site revealed the duplicate question (and answer) immediately. It's _always_ worth making a MWE:-)